# Как правильно прописать shebang в python на ubuntu?

Tags: python

Приветствую. Как проверить путь к Python на Ubuntu, что бы написать его в shebang? Похоже что он у меня в usr/bin по умолчанию. А везде пишут еще env... Или у всех по-разному?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Команда which python покажет путь к Python.

Команда env в shebang используется как раз для того, чтобы путь не писать. Это делает скрипт переносимым.

Comment: Спасибо! Значит #!usr/bin/env python3